# Adding new pair of objects into object array, vanilla is

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to push the value of the prompts into the array, with keys (rest of code depends on the keys being present and correct). I can't seem to push the additions into the array.

```
  var cWords = [
                        {word: "Hot", antonym: "Cold"},
                        {word: "Sweet", antonym: "Sour"} 
                        ];


btnAdd.eventListener("click", function (){
      var inputC = prompt("Add your word here");
      var inputA = prompt("Add corresponding word");

        var ac = ({word: + inputC} + {antonym: inputA});
        cWords.push(ac);
```

Can't seem to add successfully, getting the output [object: object] into the array.

If theres any typos, it's due to autocorrect on mobile. All syntax correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax you use is kinda weird... no need for the parenthesis and those `+` you put there in the middle. Just constract the object like the ones in the array:

```
var ac = { word: inputC, antonym: inputA };
cWords.push(ac);
```

Comment: Thanks man, that syntax was the result of trying loads of different attempts. That was the last go. Cheers dude.

Comment: @TomLee haha I see. imo there is no better way to learn than to try a few times and fail miserably, you will sure remember it from now on :D
Also please accept the answer with the green V if it solved the issue :)

Answer (score 0):

You cant assign an object like this:
`var ac = ({word: + inputC} + {antonym: inputA});`

Try this instead:

```
var ac = {word: inputC, antonym: inputA};
```